# Using preg_replace with variable to get database record

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am looking for a solution where I can use preg_replace to replace certain strings in a body of text where some of the strings may contain a variable which will then call upon a database to retrieve the replacement value (or a function which retrieves that value).

For example, I may want to replace the following strings as follows - the one in *italics* is the one I am struggling with:

`{today} => today's date`

{title} => document title

*{lang:12} => from "lang" table in database where id=12*

The first two are easy, obviously, but I am struggling with the third. The only thing I can think of is to do the replacements of all those that don't have a colon and then any which do have a colon, to trigger a function.

Comment: For ```{lang:12} => from "lang" table in database where id=12``` you want to replace lang or 12 or both of them?

Comment: @MaX the idea would be to replace the whole lot within the curly brackets with the record retrieved from the "lang" table in the database. I think yent's answer will do the trick though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can trigger a function using this :

```
$s = preg_replace_callback('/\{lang:([0-9]+)\}/', function($m) {
  $id = $m[1];
  // Mysql query
  return $string_from_database;
}, $s);
```

Even better, with required strings caching so that they won't be fetched several times from database :

```
if(preg_match_all('/\{lang:([0-9]+)\}/', $text, $m)) {
    $ids = array_unique(array_filter($m[1], function($id) {
        return (int)$id;
    }));
    $langs = array();
    if($r = mysql_query('SELECT id, txt FROM Lang WHERE id IN('.implode(', ', $ids).')')) {
        while($l = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)) $langs[$l['id']] = $l['txt'];
    }
    $text = preg_replace_callback('/\{lang:([0-9]+)\}/', function($m) use($langs) {
        $id = $m[1];
        return array_key_exists($id, $langs) ? $langs[$id] : '!!! Lang not found !!!';
    }, $text);
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly (pretty much). I had to use create_function as the server I'm working on is only on PHP 5.2 but otherwise all good! :)